# Access Values of an DataView on Change

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

In my current project i want to check if 2 bools of an DataGridView, which is linked to a DataTable, are both true and if they do i want to change the Cell which is not selected to false.
(ColumnIndex from the bools are 3 and 4)

This is my Code:

```
    private void view_summary_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        view_summary.UpdateCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            if (view_summary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "true" && view_summary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value.ToString() == "true")
            {
                view_summary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Value = false;
            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            if (view_summary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "true" && view_summary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value.ToString() == "true")
            {
                view_summary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The only problem i'm facing right now is that I can't change values. I also can only access the value which was assigned to the Cell before the change.

If i access these values with a button click i get the right values and i can change every cell.

The structure of the DataTable looks like this:

```
        dt_summary.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt_summary.Columns.Add("Betrag", typeof(string));
        dt_summary.Columns.Add("Kategorie", typeof(string));
        dt_summary.Columns.Add("Einnahme",typeof(bool));
        dt_summary.Columns.Add("Ausgabe", typeof(bool));
        dt_summary.Columns.Add("Datum", typeof(DateTime));
        view_summary.DataSource = dt_summary;
```

Comment: The row index and column index is the same in the DGV and the DataTable.  So change the value in the datatable instead of trying to change the value in the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the DataTable does not solve the problem, because changes made to the DataGridView will be visible in the DataTable after all the Event-Listeners are finished.

You can force push the changes by resetting the DataSource from your DataGridView at the start of any EventListener.
In my case this worked:

```
view_summary.DataSource=null;
view_summary.DataSource=dt_summary;
```